# Remote PHP Debugging from within WSL2 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug, remote-debugging, wsl-2

I'm running Windows 10, with a WSL2 Ubuntu instance.  I do my development within the WSL2 instance with the "Remote - WSL" extension of Visual Studio Code. So my VSC is running as a WSL2 application, not as a Windows application. I have an additional remote server (I'll refer to this as "Server X" which actually hosts/runs the PHP code. This remote server does not support the use of the "Remote - WSL" extension, so I use an "SFTP" extension to push my changes to this server. And I cannot run the code locally (in either Windows or WSL2) due to the database connection being unsupported.

I'm trying to configure remote debugging of the code on Server X from within VSC running as a WSL2 application (IE: using the "Remote - WSL" extension). The intent is to listen for a browser request to initiate the debug session.

What's happening is when I turn on "Listen for Remote Connection" in VSC when running as a WSL2 application, it doesn't detect the browser when I refresh it. I've determined the reason is because while running as a WSL2 application, my IP is different than when I'm outside WSL (which is where I'm refreshing the browser). So in short, I'm initiating a browser session outside of WSL (IP: 192.168.1.2), the remote server attempts to connect to a debugger at 192.168.1.**2**:9003, but doesn't find one because my VSC is listening on 192.168.1.**3**:9003 while it's running as a WSL2 application.

I've confirmed if I instead run VSC as a Windows application (IE: not using Remote - WSL extension on WSL2 instance) everything works fine after adjusting some setting paths to point to Windows PHP rather than WSL2 PHP.

I've been trying to play around with using SSH tunnels to re-route my port 443 traffic from Windows through WSL, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Has anyone run into this issue and have any idea how to get around it? Or is what I'm trying to do unsupported/discouraged?

Comment: > I've been trying to play around with using SSH tunnels to re-route my port 443 traffic from Windows through WSL, but have been unsuccessful so far. — why port 443? Xdebug communicates on 9003, not on 443. — What is important that Xdebug can connect to a port 9003, whether that is a remote forwarded SSH port on localhost, or a real IP address.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly; you're running VSCode from inside your WSL2 instance, which means that the IP address of your user (browser) does not match the IP address running VSCode? If this is the case, the solution should be to configure `xdebug.client_host` and disable `xdebug.discover_client_host` (https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#client_host)

Comment: @Derick  Port 443 because that's what my web requests use.  I'm relying on `xdebug.discover_client_host` which automatically attempts an xdebug connection (on port 9003) based on the where the web request came from. So right now the web request is coming from 192.168.1.2, so that's where it's attempting the xdebug session. But I'm not listening at that IP. The crux of the problem is that the web request is issued by a different IP than where I'm trying to debug from.

Comment: Though, it did just occur to me I might be able to disable `xdebug.discover_client_host` and hardcode the IP to 192.168.1.3.  I'm not a huge fan of hardcoding that though.

Comment: @Duroth Yep, thank you. I just realized this while typing my last comment. I'm just going to go this route. It's simpler than trying to reroute my web traffic. And I'm fortunate that no one else needs to debug PHP code. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I know what `discover_client_host` does, I do maintain Xdebug ;-). Instead of hard coding `client_host`, there might be a different host name. Have a look at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W-NzNtExf5C4eOu3rRQm1WlWnbW44u3ANDDA49d3FD4/edit#

Comment: Ah, and when I just went to make this change, I realized the IP of WSL changes, so this is likely how this accounts for that detail. So I'm not explicitly using Docker, but is Docker used under the covers to facilitate the "Remote - WSL" extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So WSL runs under the 172.16. 0.0/12 private address range and is not directly accessible by anything external to the host Windows machine. As such, populating `xdebug.client_host` with this IP, will not work.

My initial idea of using port forwarding was correct, but not in the direction I thought.  Instead of redirecting the outgoing web traffic (443 since my site is using SSL) from Windows through WSL, then redirect from WSL to Server X. I instead just needed to redirect the incoming xdebug traffic (9003) from Windows to WSL. (Probably what @Derick was alluding to)

To do this, I left xdebug configured as it normally would have been if WSL wasn't in the picture.

So:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=profile,debug
xdebug.idekey=<ide key value here>
xdebug.client_host=<ip of windows host, as backup>
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.trigger_value=<my trigger value>
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

Then, using the following PowerShell script on the Windows host to redirect port 9003 from the Windows host to the WSL guest:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {   
  $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}

$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"
$found = $remoteport -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if ($found) {
  $remoteport = $matches[0];
}
else {
  Write-Output "IP address could not be found";
  exit;
}

$ports = @(9003);

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++) {
  $port = $ports[$i];
  Invoke-Expression "netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port";
  Invoke-Expression "netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name=$port";

  Invoke-Expression "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport";
  Invoke-Expression "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=$port dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$port";
}

Invoke-Expression "netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4";
```

Above script is modified from the script found here:(https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22)
Which itself is modified from here: (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723)

Note*: You have to install `net-tools` in the WSL guest in order for the above script to work, so: `sudo apt install net-tools`.